# What are some Gemarot that contain a lot of stories and aggadah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, torah-study, agada-stories-legends

Looking for a list of Gemara's that has lots of aggadic stories.
The following can be excluded from the list- Avoda Zara and Perek Chelek in Sanhedrin.

Comment: I'd say Taanis!

Comment: Maybe just learn Ein Yaakov.

Comment: Brachos has a decent amount,also maybe do some Avos Dreb Nosson

Comment: Motion to close as Opinion Based

Comment: What would make an answer "canonical"?

Comment: This link (contents of Ein Yaakov) is an almost complete list. https://www.sefaria.org/Ein_Yaakov?tab=contents

Comment: Here’s one for the Maharsha chiddushei Aggados which would also encompass almost every single one https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud/Bavli/Acharonim%20on%20Talmud/Chidushei%20Agadot

Comment: @Chatzkel wow that list is great because it helps put into perspective how much aggadah is in each masechet, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Much of [Bava Basra Perek 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.73a.3-11) contains a whole slew of stories told by sailors and other people to different Amoraim. The Artscroll (and the book *the juggler and the king*) both explain these allegorically if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

בבא מציעא - השוכר את הפועלים

From the beginning of the perek [.דף פג](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.83a.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Comment: Can you share why you think this is a good suggestion? As it stands, it’s just the name of a chapter and a page number. We could end up with hundreds of such answers with no way to evaluate them.

Comment: @Alex it has everything that was asked for, I don't see a reason why I need to add more details. As with all other espouses, you can look up the source and judge for yourself

Comment: It meets the literal standard of what the question asked for, but the more research an answer requires of a reader the less useful it is. Right now this is the only answer posted, so it wouldn’t be terribly difficult to look it up, but if ten other people post different chapter names or page numbers it will become a significant burden to look up each one. By explaining why you think this is a good Gemara to learn, you make it much more helpful. By not providing a reason, you may leave readers wondering if it is just an example picked randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Id say most of *Mesechas Sanhedrin*, its packed with *Agadata's*.

Answer (score 0):

Shabbos is absolutely packed, look at the 2nd, 6th, 9th, 16th perakim, as well as the gemara about elisha baal kenafayim which appears in the 4th and 19th perakim. I think there's also a bit in Bechoros, look in the sefer "ביואר על כמה אגדות" from the Gra.

Answer (score 0):

Ninth Perek of maseches brachot

Answer (score 0):

Ein Yaakov is a Sefer which consolidates all of the agadita from the Talmud on one place for easy access. There is some halacha for example it opens up with the beginning of meseches brachos. I think this is likely though because it still contains a story.

This will be the easiest place to find what you are looking for in one place.